# How can I add a image with php in Wordpress Editor?

Tags: php, wordpress, editor, wp-editor

I use a wordpress theme. This theme contains `wp_editor` on the editor panel. My codes are:

```
<?php 
    wp_editor('', lovephotoValue, $settings = array(
       'quicktags'=>1,
       'tinymce'=>1,
       'media_buttons'=>0,
       'textarea_rows'=>10, 
       'editor_class'=>"textareastyle"
    )); 
?>
```

So, how can I add a image programmatically to this editor, when user open this page, then the image will be on the editor...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the built-in wordpress media uploader just change the value of media_buttons to true:

```
wp_editor('', lovephotoValue, $settings = array(
   'quicktags'=>1,
   'tinymce'=>1,
   'media_buttons'=>true,
   'textarea_rows'=>10, 
   'editor_class'=>"textareastyle"
));
```